# Read from stdin using read

Tags: c++, file, stdin, cat

I'm using the following code to read from stdin

```
int size;
int bufferSize=2000;
char echoString[bufferSize];
while ((size = read(fileno(stdin), echoString, bufferSize)) > 0){
 write(fileno(stdout), echoString, size);
}
```

To write the data got from stdin on the screen... but it just dont work well.
If i do a cat "hugetarfile.tar.gz" | ./myprogram | tar -zvt it works, but on the end it "crashed" telling there are some trash.
If i do cat "hugetarfile.tar.gz" | tar -zvt it works like a charm..

on the end of the tar you can see:

gzip: stdin: decompression OK, trailing garbage ignored
tar: Child returned status 2
added the File *fin = freopen(nill, "rb", "stdin")

Someone can help me? xD

Just to tell... i'm creating the read to send trough socket, but in this case this war is easier to test.

Comment: Why not use `cin.read` and `cout.write`? I think that `read` and `write` are only for sockets

Comment: You may need to read from `stdin` and write to `stdout` in binary mode: `freopen(NULL, "rb", stdin);` and `freopen(NULL, "wb", stdout);` would do it I think.

Comment: I can read almost the entire file, it seems on the end it comes with trash.

Comment: I need to use the freopen to read instead of read?

Comment: No. use `freopen()` to reopen `stdout` and `stdin`. Call them before you use `read()` and `write()`.

Comment: i did fin=freopen(NULL, "rb", stdin)... but how i read trough the entire data?

Comment: Do you, anywhere in your program other than what you have shown us, write to stdout? Do you have a "printf" or "fprintf" anywhere at all?

Comment: I need to write it on a char and send it trouch socket

Comment: You don't need to store the return value from `freopen()` in this instance, or with `freopen(NULL, "wb", stdout)` as will be `stdin` and `stdout` respectively. Just read the data as before.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but instead of using `fileno(stdin)`/`fileno(stdout)` you can also use `STDIN_FILENO`/`STDOUT_FILENO`.

Comment: Same problem even with the freopen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completed your program in the simplest way to make it compile without warning with `gcc -ansi -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -Wall -W demonofnight.c`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int size;
    int const bufferSize=2000;
    char echoString[bufferSize];
    while ((size = read(fileno(stdin), echoString, bufferSize)) > 0){
        write(fileno(stdout), echoString, size);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and executed it with

```
cat bigFile | ./a.out | md5sum
```

for several big files. I got the same md5 than with `md5sum bigFile`.

Conclusion: the error is in what you don't show us.

Comment: @MooingDuck, mention of `cat "hugetarfile.tar.gz" | ./myprogram | tar -zvt` hints at a POSIX system where line endings isn't a problem.  And I don't know enough about Windows to be sure, but I would have expected that text/binary doesn't export to the read/write interface (but I expect it to be present at fread/fwrite).

Comment: Sorrym but i ran the same program with the ./a.out and directly and the returns are differents

Comment: You have a different effect with ./a.out and myprog? Is there another program named myprog in your path? Do you have . in your path?

Answer (score 0):

You must test for errors in your read and write. Why don't you test your program like:

```
./myprogram < hugetarfile.tar.gz > output.tar.gz
```

and make sure that hugetarfile.tar.gz and output.tar.gz are the same.

Regards

Comment: i did that... and those are not the same

Comment: Can you describe how they differ? if output.tar is bigger, what does the extra data look like?